# Image processing using openCV python code on images uploaded online in real time

Tags: python, opencv, heroku

I'm new to cloud computing and i am posting this question after doing good google searches and coming up with unsatisfactory answers. *(I am aware of the fact that this is a general doubt, but due to the lack of proper articles on this topic i posted a question here)*

**I want to create a web interface which enables the user to upload images on which i want my opencv-python code to do processing and then output the resultant image and some text.**

I have checked out heroku and was able to import opencv-python-numpy-scipy buildpack. I didn't have much success due to import issues. So i did a trial run with a sample code which is purely python based. The output was visible in the logs of my heroku app. How do i get the output onto a webpage and how do i proceed with my original image processing app assuming i have fixed all the import issues? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Start by looking into python-based web-frameworks. I myself am using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)  for this purpose, but if you require a very simple web page, you can used flask or others instead.

Comment: @iamai a normal web-page would suffice (i can build it myself). But how do i link it with my opencv-python code? I even tried pythonanywhere.com but for that too, i wasnt able to find good documentation or articles on how to deploy it there.